# Trackpad freezes after suspend Ryzen 2500U

Tags: grub2, touchpad, 19.10, huawei, amd-ryzen

I am using a Huawei Matebook 14D with AMD Ryzen 2500U with Ubuntu 19.10. My Trackpad freezes everytime I wake up my system from sleep. Also experiencing some random keyboard & system freezes (not as often as trackpad freezes though). Here's how my grub file (/etc/default/grub) looks like -

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor idle=nomwait iommu=soft processor.max_cstate=1 i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

All the changes made to the grub file come from various random sources on the internet. Please help!

Comment: The line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` is cut in the middle.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was copied wrong. Edited the question.